# IndexError: pop from empty list

Tags: python

I need help. I have no idea why I am getting this error. The error is in `fname = 1st.pop()`

```
for i in range(num) :
        fname = lst.pop()
        lTransfer   = [(os.path.join(src, fname),           os.path.join(dst, fname)),
                       (os.path.join(src, fname) + ".md5",  os.path.join(dst, fname) + ".md5")]
        for tFiles in lTransfer:
            #
            # copy the file
            #
            try :
                shutil.copyfile(tFiles[0], tFiles[1])
                os.chmod(tFiles[1], 0o777)
                success += 1
            except :
                ErrList.append(sys.exc_info())
                print(ErrList[-1])
                x = 0

    if success != num:
        msg  = "CopyRandomFilesToFolder src=%s, dst=%s, desired count=%d, Success=%d\n"%(src, dst, num, success)

        self._oLogger.LocalWriteLog(self._testname, 'CCmgCefHelper', msg, 0)

    return success
```

#

Comment: You are receiving this error because you are trying to `pop` from `lst` but `lst` is empty.

Comment: either your list is empty or your range is larger than the length of your list

Comment: Perhaps provide the code that sets up `lst`

Comment: Why not use `for fname in lst:`?!

Comment: lSpecialFiles   = []
        for sFile in os.listdir(src):
            base, ext = os.path.splitext(sFile)

Comment: if ext.lower() == ".md5" and os.path.exists(os.path.join(src, base)):
                for sSpecial in lSpecial:
                    if sSpecial.lower() in base.lower():
                        lSpecialFiles.append(base)

Comment: lst.extend(lSpecialFiles)

Comment: @user3597409 Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24048405/edit) this code into the question. In python, indentation matters, and we can't see any indentation in the comments

Comment: Sorry! just getting used to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lst` has less elements than num

use

```
for i in range(min(num, len(lst))):`
```

or something like

```
for fname in reversed(lst):# reversed to continue the pop order
   #your code
```

**Explanation**

```
#lets say we have
num = 4
data = [1,2,3]

for i in range(num): # range(4) = [0,1,2,3] so it witl repeat you code 4 times
    data.pop() #remove last element
#first 3 times, it works, but at the last one 'data' is empty, so you get an exception
```

if you do:

```
for i in range(min(num , len(data))):
# min(num , len(data)) = min(4,3) = 3
# so you get the corrent number of iterations
```

Finally:

```
for fname in reversed(data):
#is the same to
for fname in [3,2,1]:
#'reversed' just change the order of your list
#so it will work in this order, 3, 2 and finishes with 1
```

Hope it helps

Comment: So get rid of my for i in range and just use the for fname in reversed

Comment: @user3597409 yes, it should be enough

Comment: So can you explain to me what this does. I am kind of a newbie.

Comment: @user3597409 done, hope it helps you to understand better now